# check if condition in ajax success data

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to check if condition in ajax success call and append  value=0 and option as no client with data. flag=0 or flag=1.data received in success is `{INDPN_00: "Test_Dedicated"}`.I want to append {0: "no client"} with data value as {INDPN_00: "Test_Dedicated",0: "no client"} if flag=0

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : "{{url('getProject')}}",
    data : {customer_name : customer_name,user_name: user_name,sl_flag:sl_flag},
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(data){
        $('#project_name').find('option').remove();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {   
            $('#project_name')
            .append($("<option></option>")
            .text(value).attr("value",key)); 
        });
        $("#project_name option[value="+proj_selected+"]").attr('selected','selected'); 
    },error: function () {
        alert('request failed');
    } 
});
```

Is it possible to do that

Comment: where is the value of "flag" coming from? It's not clear.

Comment: value from text box

Comment: `data` is just an object so yeah you can add a new property to it. Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wbao62po/